# How do I find whether all ajax requests are completed and each request returned data from server to HTML using Javascript and/or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to perform some slideup and slidedown animations in my DOM (HTML page). The number of AJAX requests may vary in each page.

My question is, How do I know whether all AJAX requests in a page has completed and each request completed returning data from server to HTML?

Once I get this done, I can perform my animations after these things in DOM.

Comment: Without your code I can only recommend some concepts ... one concept is Promises and `Promise.all` - another concept is a count of pending ajax calls, when it hits 0 then all calls are done

Answer (score 0):

-- Updated after comment discussion --

I would fire all my ajax in the same section.

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(), // some ajax
    $.ajax() // some more ajax
    // etc etc for all
).then(function() {
    // play animations here
});
```

This way you fire them all at the start once they are all done the then will execute.

-- Old alternate Awnser --

I had a similar issue a while back have a read throught this:

[Stoping jquery .then chain via user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339461/stoping-jquery-then-chain-via-user-input).

Basicly you want to chain your ajax responses.

Also read up here:
http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: that's the slow way of doing things - sequential ajax

Comment: Doesnt have to be you can create indepentent queues or chains depending on the desired result.

Comment: so, multiple parallel queues is easier to work with than multiple single calls?

Comment: Depends what you want i wouldnt say its easier but if you have server ajax calls that on result fire more ajax calls I prefer chains but again its case dependant.

Comment: Re reading the question i think your correct in saying a chain is slow.

Comment: I'd say your answer will not help too much ... next question would be (I predict) ... "how do I know when all queues are done" :p

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are after but you can check how many AJAX calls are active using

```
$.active
```

so if there are none all AJAX calls have finished, and you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function) for more info.

And you could use the success and error properties of your AJAX calls to build in checks to ensure they are returning etc.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to create a flag variable like say ajaxRequest = true and then change this variable to false whenever an ajax request is failed. Then do your things on behalf of this variable, like:

```
if(!!ajaxRequest){
  //if all the ajax are sucessfull.
}else{
  //if any of them fails.
}
```